# Plotly R converts numeric factor levels to numeric values

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have a basic data frame like this, and I am trying to plot x vs. y in plotly. It for some reason converts my x values to numeric (continuous scale) and plots instead of keeping them as factors. Any idea why it would do that and what I can do to make it behave differently (correctly)?

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32), y = 1:6)
df$x <- as.factor(df$x)

str(df)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","4","8",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6
 $ y: int  1 2 3 4 5 6

levels(df$x)
[1] "1"  "2"  "4"  "8"  "16" "32"
```

Plotting with `ggplot`, which obviously does the right thing:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
```

Plotting with `plotly` R, which treats x as a continuous value:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(df, x = x, y = y, mode = 'markers')
```

Comment: as alternative you could just use ggplotly()

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to make it work as ggplot2 would, you can force the x variable in plotly to display the factor's labels:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(df, x = labels(x), y = y, mode = 'markers')
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I did not know that option. Thank you. It solves part of my problem. Now, my labels are dna mutation positions like 41234470, and even with this option, the axis labels get abbreviated to 41.2M as if it is a numeric value.

Comment: You can use `plot_ly(df, x = x, y = y, mode = 'markers') %>% layout(xaxis = list(type = "category"))` to solve the other issue. `ggplotly()` handles factors by forcing the xaxis values to be numeric but adds ticklabels that match factor labels.