# Plotly R: Cant get points to plot when two values present per x factor level

Tags: r, plotly

I have a data frame like this:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(x = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L), .Label = c("41197708", "41223094", "41244000", "41244435", 
"41244936"), class = "factor"), y = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2)), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Trying to print a scatter plot with points as follows:

```
plot_ly(df, x = levels(x), y = y, mode = 'markers')
```

I only see points corresponding to y = 1 and not y = 2. Any idea why?

The following works in plotly, but then it treats x axis values as numeric / continuous (not what I want):

```
plot_ly(df, x = x, y = y, mode = 'markers')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this a duplicate of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122216) and related to this [github issue](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/578) ?

> Currently you need to manually specify that you have a categorical
>   axis.
>
> ```
> plot_ly(df, x = x, y = y, mode = "markers") %>% layout(xaxis = list(type = "category"))
> ```
>
> Right now we just sent the factor levels as a string to
>   plotly.js
>
> `plotly_build(plot_ly(df, x = x, y = y, mode = "markers"))$data[[1]]$x`
>
> Based on those strings, plotly.js (correctly) thinks that you want a
>   numeric axis. In the future, we should set smarter axis type defaults
>   based on the variable mappings.

If you do:

```
plot_ly(df, x = x, y = y, mode = "markers") %>% 
      layout(xaxis = list(type = "category"))
```

You'll get:

[image]

Comment: `x` is already a factor. I don't want the x-axis to convert these values to millions on a continuous numeric scale, which plotly does when I use just `x` or `factor(x)`.