# R plotly x axis character / factor (combination number and -). plot only showing axis that contain numbers only. bug?

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to use `plotly` to plot a bar chart with strings (combination number) as x-axis.
("1", "2", "3", "4 - 5", "6 - 8","9 - 13", "14 - 21", "22 - 34", "35 - 55")

However, Only 3 data is being ploted. ("1", "2", "3")

Here is the code:

```
library(plotly)

dfb = structure(groups = c("1", "2", "3", "4 - 5", "6 - 8",
                        "9 - 13", "14 - 21", "22 - 34", "35 - 55"),
    counts = c(29090,10074, 4573, 4029, 2289, 1120, 337, 78, 15)),
  class = c("data.frame"),
  row.names = c(NA,-9L),
  .Names = c("groups","counts")
)

  plot_ly(dfb,
      x = groups,
      y = counts,
      type = "bar")
```

returns:

[image]

But if I filtered on of groups that contain only numbers, it is working well:

```
  dfc=subset(dfb,dfb$groups!='1')
  plot_ly(dfc,
      x = groups,
      y = counts,
      type = "bar")
```

[image]

Why is this happening?
And how to solve this?

I'm using plotly because I want to used it with Shiny, and for now it is the most fit for me.

I didn't use ggplotly (make ggplot and then convert it to plotly) because sometimes axis tittle being cut off.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is a duplicated question: [Plotly R: Cant get points to plot when two values present per x factor level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37284287/plotly-r-cant-get-points-to-plot-when-two-values-present-per-x-factor-level). However here you have a couple of solutions:

**Solution 1** *(also proposed in the referred question)*:

```
library(plotly)

dfb = data.frame(groups= c("1", "2", "3", "4 - 5", "6 - 8","9 - 13", "14 - 21", "22 - 34", "35 - 55"),
            counts=c(29090,10074, 4573, 4029, 2289, 1120, 337, 78, 15))

plot_ly(dfb,
   x = groups,
   y = counts,
   type = "bar") %>%
   layout(xaxis=list(type='category'))
```

**Solution 2** *(way less elegant)*

```
groups_str <- c("1", "2", "3", "4 - 5", "6 - 8","9 - 13", "14 - 21", "22 - 34", "35 - 55")
groups <- 1:length(groups_str)

dfb = data.frame(groups= groups,
            counts=c(29090,10074, 4573, 4029, 2289, 1120, 337, 78, 15))

plot_ly(dfb,
   x = groups,
   y = counts,
   type = "bar") %>%
   layout(xaxis=list(tickmode='array', tickvals=groups, ticktext=groups_str))
```

**Both produce the figure** *(with different xaxis title, though)*
[image]